# Extract text between two tags using Regex

Tags: java, xml, regex, perl, parsing

I have a text file in this format:

```
   <seg id="1"> They are the same thing. Let's shoot them both. </seg>
   <seg id="1"> We can't wait for you to move back either. </seg>
   <seg id="2"> You seem quite uptight. </seg>
   <seg id="3"> Does your wife (who is also your sister) not give it up any more? </seg>
   <seg id="1"> Can domestic violence abusers be rehabilitated? http://usat.ly/1rwvgWf </seg>
   <seg id="1"> Taulia enables Fortune 500 businesses to electronically handle </seg>
   <seg id="2"> all invoicing and payment to their suppliers </seg>
```

I would like to get the content of the tags in the following format:

```
   They are the same thing. Let's shoot them both.
   We can't wait for you to move back either.You seem quite uptight.Does your wife (who is also your sister) not give it up any more?
   Can domestic violence abusers be rehabilitated? http://usat.ly/1rwvgWf
   Taulia enables Fortune 500 businesses to electronically handle all invoicing and payment to their suppliers
```

As you can see the content of seg id="1",seg id="2",seg id="3" are printed in the same line because they are one post. Also, the content of seg id="1", and seg id="2" are printed in same line.

I'm thinking of using java and Regex, but I would like to know if there is another way to get what I need.

Comment: Do you just want to remove the opening and removing `<seg>` element tags? Or do you want to actually match an array of the contents of the `<seg>` elements?

Comment: I want to match an array of the contents of the <seg> elements. in the example you can could say that seg 1,2,3 are acutaly one post. So I would like to combine them all in one post. I would like to know if anybody has an idea of how to deal with that...

Comment: Er, an XML Parser? Looks like SAX + StringBuilder is all you need.

Answer (score 2):

For each line `line`:

```
line = line.replaceAll("<.*?>(.*?)</.*?>", "$1");
```

- Detect opening `<.*?>`
- and closing `</.*?>` tag
- create the group 1 `(.*?)` between
- replace the whole matching expression by the group `$1`.

Answer (score 2):

The results will be in capture group one, if you do a match of:

```
/<seg\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/seg>/g
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/rW8xF2/1)

Comment: The output is different from what I want. What I want is making seg 1,2,3 to be printed in one line not in separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try the next:

```
String input = "   <seg id=\"1\"> They are the same thing. Let's shoot them both. </seg>\n   <seg id=\"1\"> We can't wait for you to move back either. </seg>\n   <seg id=\"2\"> You seem quite uptight. </seg>\n   <seg id=\"3\"> Does your wife (who is also your sister) not give it up any more? </seg>\n   <seg id=\"1\"> Can domestic violence abusers be rehabilitated? http://usat.ly/1rwvgWf </seg>";

String[] array = input.replaceAll("\\s*<seg[^>]+>", "").split("</seg>");
```

If you read the file line by line, the best option is:

```
String line = line.replaceAll("</?seg[^>]*>");
```

If you want to remove the leading and trailing space:

```
String line = line.replaceAll("\\s*</?seg[^>]*>\\s*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you can try this will help you a lot.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = qq(<seg id="1"> They are the same thing. Let's shoot them both. </seg>
   <seg id="1"> We can't wait for you to move back either. </seg>
   <seg id="2"> You seem quite uptight. </seg>
   <seg id="3"> Does your wife (who is also your sister) not give it up any more? </seg>
   <seg id="1"> Can domestic violence abusers be rehabilitated? http://usat.ly/1rwvgWf </seg>
   <seg id="1"> Taulia enables Fortune 500 businesses to electronically handle </seg>
   <seg id="2"> all invoicing and payment to their suppliers </seg>);
$string =~ s{<seg(?: [^>]+)?>((?:(?!</?seg[ >]).)*)</seg>}{$1}ig;
print $string;exit;
```

Comment: Thanks,,,, But this not what I want. what I want is that the seg1,2,3 should be printed in the same line like this: "We can't wait for you to move back either.You seem quite uptight.Does your wife (who is also your sister) not give it up any more?"      and seg1,2 should be printed in the same line "Taulia enables Fortune 500 businesses to electronically handle all invoicing and payment to their suppliers"

Answer (score 0):

Don't even attempt it. XML is not a regular language [technical term] so regular expressions are the wrong tool for the job. See the famous post here:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Use an XML parser.